# I would like to learn from you guys on amending my code

Tags: python

My code:

```
sent = 'I am honest!I do!I do!I really do!'

for i in sentence:
    if i == '!':
        print(i, end='')
```

Expected Output:

```
I am honest!
I do!
I do!
I really do!
```

Much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. I think https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is the right place for this question. That said, you might want to have a look at [`str.split()` and `str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html).

Comment: @Aufziehvogel, OP code is not working and they not look for review/advise for improvements.

Comment: Oh, I see, then my fault :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for i in sent.split('!')[:-1]:
    print(i+'!')

I am honest!
I do!
I do!
I really do!
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's start from your code. First problem is name mismatch - `sent` vs `sentence`. Then closest to what you tried would be:

```
sentence = 'I am honest!I do!I do!I really do!'

for char in sentence:
    if char == '!':
        print(char)
    else:
        print(char, end='')
```

Others have shown other possible approaches. Yet two more would be

```
sentence = 'I am honest!I do!I do!I really do!'
print('!\n'.join(sentence.split('!')))
```

or

```
print(sentence.replace('!', '!\n'))
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! @buran

I was actually got stuck on a similar question as well! Wondering how to fix my code.

My code:

`sentence = 'I am honest!I do!I do!I really do!'
    amount=input("Please input the number of '!'(s) that you want to print before stop printing? ")
    for j in sentence:
        if amount='1':
            if j == '!':
                print(j)
                break
            else:
                print(j, end='')
        if amount='2':`

Cannot think of any way that will work if the amount entered is 2...

Comment: Expected output:
`Please input the number of '!'(s) that you want to print before stop printing? 3
I am honest!
I do!
I do!`

Answer (score 0):

To keep your code at maximum, you can store the caracters until you see the `!`, then you print, and goes again to the next one

```
sentence = 'I am honest!I do!I do!I really do!'
to_print = ""
for i in sentence:
    to_print += i
    if i == '!':
        print(to_print)
        to_print = ""
```

You can also use a regex `[\w\s]+!` meaning a suite of chars&space ended by a `!`

```
import re

sentence = 'I am honest!I do!I do!I really do!'
for i in re.findall(r"[\w\s]+!", sentence):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

One-liner:

```
[print(f'{a}!') for a in 'I am honest!I do!I do!I really do!'.split('!') if a]
```

Output:

```
I am honest!
I do!
I do!
I really do!
```

Answer (score 0):

Or by using `re.split`

```
import re
s =re.split("!", sent)
s = filter(None, s)

for word in s:
    print(word+"!")
```